# Adding a sub-menu to this menu?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a dropdown to the "Case Studies" section of this menu, but still have it remain responsive in mobile devices.

Here's my code:

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e2e2e2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #e2e2e2;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.topnav li a:hover {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: none;
}
/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/blog.php">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/blog.php">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sorry for a silly question here, I just can't get my head around it. I think I've learned a lot lately and now I'm at capacity for a while or something. I'm pretty worn out! Lol.

Anyone who can help?

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: Could you make a working Plunkr or something? Is it possible for you to just add an other <ul> in your <li>? 

E.g: <ul><li>menu link<ul><li>sub menu</li></ul></li><li>Other link</li>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wdnkem9a/ is a working version of the navigation.

If I add an extra <UL> unfortunately it just dumps that info below in a block, rather than it working as I would want (click/touch on mobile phone)

Comment: I probably don't get what you want. To make it clickable just do what you did in this example? <a href="#"> around the text?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I've not been clear.

What I want to happen is when I "mouse over" (or, on a smartphone, click with my finger) on one of the options, a dropdown menu to appear, with additional options.

For example, when I mouseover the "Case Studies" option, I want a dropdown that says "Case study 1, case study 2, etc" :)

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't style it, but is this what you want? Just use display:none; to hide it and display:block; when you want it to appear. (https://jsfiddle.net/wdnkem9a/1/) (Check line 17 & 18 in de CSS)

Comment: This doesn't work :(